# Modifying destructured react state will update the component's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have the following function for saving an appointment:

```
handleAppointmentSave = event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const { appointment } = this.state

    const appointmentErrors = apppointmentFormIsValid(appointment)
    this.setState({ appointmentErrors })
    if (!(Object.keys(appointmentErrors).length === 0)) return
    const localeDate = appointment.transactionDate.toLocaleString()
    appointment.transactionDate = moment
      .tz(localeDate, 'DD.MM.YYYY, HH:mm', 'UTC')
      .format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

    const { saveAppointment, history } = this.props
    
    saveAppointment(appointment)
      .then(appointmentId => {
        debugger;
      })
      .catch(error => {
      })
  }
```

My issue is with the destructured statement `const { appointment } = this.state`. When I'm modifying the destructured appointment `transactionDate`, the `this.state.appointment.transactionDate` is also changed. Although this does not trigger a rerender right away and everything is fine when redux `state` updates as a result of clicking the `saveAppointment` action, a rerender will be triggered and the malformed `transactionDate` will break a date picker component.

The only solution that I found so far is to make a deep copy of the state's appointment before saving id and work on that:

```
const appointment = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.appointment));
appointment.transactionDate = this.state.appointment.transactionDate;
```

Is this the only solution and normal behavior?

Comment: Since all objects are by reference in javascript, any modification you make will be reflected in the original. And react will not react to it since the reference has not changed. You can also do something like `const appointmentCopy = {...appointment}`

Comment: With the same approach you can store the new date in some `const newDate` and then do `saveAppointment({ ...appointment, transactionDate: newDate })`.

Comment: Thank you. Those are indeed cleaner approaches

Comment: I think your comments cover the answer to this question. If you wish you can add an answer. Since as you mentioned all objects are by reference, I assume this is a bad React practice to update the state by mistake through derefrencing.